# PHP-FPM Docker container does not create Unix socket file

Tags: docker, drupal, fpm

I'm running PHP-FPM and Nginx in separate Docker containers, and they communicate well when using TCP sockets.

To increase speed, I'm trying to switch to using a Unix socket for communication, but for some reason the PHP-FPM is not creating the socket.

My PHP-FPM image is based on drupal:8-FPM, and what I believe is the problem is that it doesn't create the unix socket at runtime.

My Dockerfile overrides the `/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` to add lines such as these:

```
listen = /run/docker.sock
```

However, the file doesn't get created by the container.

Any advice on how to troubleshoot this issue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding a new file instead of overwriting the www.conf file. Details: https://www.reddit.com/r/drupal/comments/91r2tn/phpfpm_nginx_in_docker_change_fastcgirequests/e4ib5mq